# How to activate JS file in a separate folder

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JS and I've tried many different ways to try and get this to work but to no avail. (I looked at the other posts but their solution didnt work for me)

My project folder is organized as follows:

```
+-+ project
  +-- css
  +-+ js
  | +-- index_js.js
  +-- index.html
```

I have got it to work with the index_js.js file outside of the js folder by assigning the script tag src to src="index_js.js". But when I try to assign it to src="../js/index_js.js" while it is in the js folder it doesn't work and won't give me an alert. I have also tried to assign src="/js/index_js.js" but it still does not work.

My index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/index_js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My index_js.js is:

```
alert("inside of the js folder");
```

Comment: can you attach a screenshot of your folder? something seems to be wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That needs to be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index_js.js"></script>
```

Or even:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/index_js.js"></script>
```

By specifying `../js`, you're searching for a `js` directory which is on the same level as your `project` directory.

Comment: @OpMt This is the best answer. Define your "it didn't work".

Comment: Your update to your question shows that you tried `/js/index_js.js` instead of `js/index_js.js`

Comment: restarted my browser and it worked for some reason.. Will mark this as answer in 5 minutes since stack doesn't let me accept the answer right away..

Answer (score 1):

Your index.html should be like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index_js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As mentioned in my other comment I tried this already before and it didnt work :/

Comment: If that is the case, your project folder is not organised as you say it is.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
src="../js/index_js.js"
```

in the code will look for the "index_js.js" the parent folder of "project".

```
../ refers to up one level.
```

In the given code, you are at /project/index.html
When you do ../ you are moving to the parent folder i.e /root/project/

Now, when you give

```
src="../js/index_js.js"
```

it looks for the js file at:
/root/js/index_js.js

The correct code would be:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/index_js.js"></script>
</body>
```

or

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index_js.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

By expressing `"../"` you will quit your current `project` folder an move to the root folder. Your script then tries to find the subfolder "js" and the file in a directory that does not exist. Your correct code would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/index_js.js"></script>
```

Comment: I also tried that but it still did not work :/ didnt mention it in the post i'll add that in. The reason why I tried that was because i saw that in one of the solutions from someone else's post

Comment: Slash in the beginning works only if in the project's root folder

Answer (score 0):

Since, you have the js folder on the same directory as your index.html file, you don't need to use any backslashes.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index_js.js"></script>
```

Now make sure;

- You have `js` folder and `index.html` file both in the same
  directory.
- The folder name `js` is as you have mentioned.
- The file name is correctly placed i.e `index_js.js` and it is inside the `js` folder.